# MYSQL: Counting the occurences of distinct values depending on its date

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

i am trying to find a MYSQL query that will find distinct values in a particular field, count the number of occurences of that value depending of its date.

example db:

```
in_date     item_code       
---------   ---------
2015/11/25  item1
2015/11/25  item2
2015/12/10  item1
2015/12/10  item1
2015/12/10  item2
2016/01/01  item1
```

expected output:

```
Date          Item1     Item2
----------    -----     -----
2015/11/25    1         1
2015/12/10    2         1
2016/01/01    1         0
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select date, sum(item_code = 'item1') as item1,
       sum(item_code = 'item2') as item2
from t
group by date;
```